# How can I skip error field during `Unmarshal` in go?

Tags: go

I am using `json.Unmarshal(body, outputStruct)` to convert bytes array to a struct. There could be errors during unmarshal.

For example, the struct is:

```golang
type Item struct {
    Price       float64  `json:"price"`
    Quantity    int      `json:"quantity"`
}
```

It throws error if I pass `quantity` as a float value rather than integer. I wonder how I can only unmarshal the valid field and skip the ones with error?

So if I unmarshal a json:

```json
{ price: 10, quantity: 2.5 }
```

I'd like to only get the value `price` in the struct but leave the quantity as initial default value.

Comment: striniyfy the fields, before validation.

Comment: To ignore a JSON value that's incompatible with the target field's type you'd have to use a custom unmarshaler (i.e., a custom type that implements the [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.21.0#Unmarshaler) interface) as pointed out by @Volker in his answer.

Comment: Note however that for the specific case that you've outlined in the question you can use [`json.Number`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json@go1.21.0#Number) to _accommodate_ (not ignore) both integers and floats.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wonder how I can only unmarshal the valid field and skip the ones with error?

You cannot.

If your JSON contains floats you simply cannot unmarshal that into an int. You either have to:

1. use a float64 and handle non integers in code after unmarshaling
2. write your own UnmarshalJSON for your type
3. do a two step unmarshal, once ignoring (`"-"`) `Quantity` so it won't fail and do a second unmarshal of only Quantity (new struct) and ignore on error.

2 Is "the best" way, but I'm not sure what the logic behind "skipping fields with wrong type" would be? Which value would Quantity have if quantity is 2.5? 0? Why?

Comment: Thanks for answering. The reason is the an item can be split which will lead to a decimal. I want to unmarshal all other fields and left the quantity out if it is decimal. Probably the second option is the best one.